# Symfony2 passing parameter on foreign key return always null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I pass parameters on a foreign key

```
Class Product{

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var Group
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $group;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="alt_number", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $altproducts;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $product;
}
```

ProductRepo:

```
public function GetProducts($product, Group $group){
       $results = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.product= :product')
        ->andwhere('p.group= :group')
        ->setParameter('product',$product)
        ->setParameter('group',$group)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $results;
 }
```

In the Service:

```
// Param $group is an Object of Group Class
 $ProductList= $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)->GetProducts($product,$group);
```

Is always empty;

When i do `->getSQL()` I have right SQL syntax  `SELECT i0_.id AS id_0, i0_.product AS product,i0_.description AS description_2, i0_.group_id AS group_id_3, i0_.altproducts AS altproducts_4, FROM Product i0_ WHERE i0_.product = ? AND i0_.group_id = ?`

I need to get the array of altProducts based on Product number and the groupID.

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting your query to return? It doesn't return a list if you are passing it a specific product and group entities as parameters - it will return single result (in array) in case you happen to have a matching product row in your database (that is referencing to the specific group row)...

Comment: I don't quite understand your goal still: if you are querying with the product and group entities, you will get 0 or 1 product entity as result (in array) - and this product entity (if it is found) will have 1 altProducts value. If this is what you are after, then I would say that your query looks to be fine - could you check the runnable query from the profiler and check whether those product & group rows (+ the reference) exist in your database.

Comment: ah, scrap that last comment - mixed up your product entity and the product variable in the entity. The check the profiler part is still valid :)

Comment: yes its valid. In MYSQL terms `SELECT alt_numbers Where product = 'asdf' AND group_id = '3'`  which is an array is what iam trying to do.

Also why i will get 0 or 1 product entity when the product is not unique and `getResult` should return an array

Comment: 'I need to get the array of altProducts based on Product number and the groupID.' in your question sort of means that there will be only 0/1 result. But if I now understood correctly, there should be 'Product name' (or at least the Product number does not reference to the entity id) written in this definition?

Comment: Are you running this in some web page where you have access to the profiler and the actual runnable query? Could you debug the passed parameter values (to check that they match to your expected 'asdf' and group entity with id 3)

Comment: I am working on local machine also when `->getParameters()` i see product value 'asdf' and group value is a Group Object with id, groupname

Comment: sorry, meant whether you are calling this query on some page (and not for some command etc) so that you would have access to the web profiler and the query & paramaters from there (local machine is fine for that)

Comment: hmm, do you have a typo in your entity or in your printed sql? your entity has the reference column name grp_id whereas your getSql is printing out group_id

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get all products for specific group, you shouldn't pass a specific product entity as a parameter:

```
public function GetProducts(Group $group)
{
       $results = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.group= :group')
        ->setParameter('group',$group)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();

        return $results;
 }
```

Comment: I added completed entity, I need to get the altproducts for a product with the group ID